# return the first occurrence of a query result spring hql

Tags: java, spring, hql

I have an endpoint that returns a json result. It appears that some of the rows in the database are repeated. I want to retrieve just the first matching result and leave out the rest. Here is my `HQL` in the DAO

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List <Data> getDetails(String tin) {
        return  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Data where cal_no = :cal_no")
                .setParameter("cal_no",  tin).list();
    }
```

Here is the outcome format of the hql

```
[{"id":15274,"cal_NO":"37"}{"id":15275,"cal_NO":"37"}]
```

You can see that cal_NO is repeated twice because cal_no with 37 exist in the dbd twice. My challenge is just to pick the first occurrence and leave out the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Criteria` object and use `setMaxResults(1)` to get one item Or
try this piece of code :

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List <Data> getDetails(String tin) {
        List <Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        List <Data> results = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Data where cal_no = :cal_no")
                .setParameter("cal_no",  tin).list();
        if(CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(results){
            Data firstDataOccurence = results.get(0);
            dataList.add(firstDataOccurence);
            return dataList;
        }
        else{
            return ListUtils.EMPTY_LIST;
        }
    }
```